# Removing AccountTeamMember permissions

Tags: account-teams

If I remove an AccountTeamMember from an Account via Apex code by doing a delete operation, will this also remove their permissions on the account? Or will I also need to remove any corresponding records in the AccountShare table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed this also deletes the corresponding record within the AccountShare table, removing the AccountTeamMember's permissions upon deletion.